# Node - Improving Startup Speed

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I have a Node/Express app. Technically, I'm using [Feathers](http://feathersjs.com/). My app runs well once started. However, the first visit takes over one minute to load the page. After that, it runs fine for the most part. Except, after some unknown period of time, it seems to fall asleep again. When that happens, the first visit takes over one minute again to load the first page.

I'm really happy with the performance when the app is running. I'm most concerned about the "falling asleep" part, or whatever is happening.

Can someone tell me why my app would periodically do this? Is it a hosting item? Is there a setting/configuration in Node I can change to keep it alive/awake?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem can be in database connection, on in the service which is initialized at application starts.

Comment: I'm not hitting a database. I am however loading static files into memory at start. For that reason, I'm ok with the initial slow start time. But, its a problem with the sleeping part I mentioned. I'm not sure what's causing that. I'm not sure if that's a Node thing, or a Feathers thing. I haven't experienced that before

Comment: Does it do this even on your local development machine?

Comment: I'm trying that to monitor it.

Comment: Feathers doesn't really do anything during startup except establish a database connection and whatever bootstrap code you add. Without anything added it is definitely less than a second. How are you hosting it? Heroku (esp. the free tier) might put it to sleep after a certain time and if you are loading a lot of things into memory during startup that will be triggered right when the request is happening.